# No option to disable OpenGL2.0 in libgdx

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I have a laptop with bad in built video drivers which don't support OpenGL 2.0. But when coding with libGDX, I only get the option :`cfg.useGL30 = false` and not the code`cfg.useGL20 = false`. If I type this code, I get an error. It only works with GL30. I use eclipse mars. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Libgdx does not support anything below OpenGL ES 2.0 unless you use a version less than Libgdx 1.0.0. You can find old versions [here](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/releases/), or you can specify version 0.9.9 in your Gradle setup files. Beware that you may have some trouble with the current documentation not matching the old spec exactly.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for responding! If I use any older versions, will my programs run fine or will I face any major errors? I use eclipse mars which is the latest version of Eclipse and so will the older versions of libGDX be compatible with it? Thanks again!

Comment: I always use the latest Libgdx version so I'm not sure. If you target Desktop it should be fine. If you target Android I think it is likely to have serious issues with ART.

Comment: Hmmm.. Okay! Thanks for replying!